# RuntimeError: !!! multi_level_map is not a package name nor a repository name

Tags: ros, catkin, jenkins, pre-release, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't figure out why my [pre-release test](http://jenkins.willowgarage.com:8080/job/prerelease-groovy-multi_level_map/ARCH_PARAM=amd64,UBUNTU_PARAM=precise,label=prerelease/2/console) is failing.

Jenkins builds and tests all the packages, then complains:

```
Get list of wet repositories that build-depend on repo list multi_level_map
prerelease script failed. Check out the console output above for details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rosbuild/hudson/workspace/prerelease-groovy-multi_level_map/ARCH_PARAM/amd64/UBUNTU_PARAM/precise/label/prerelease/jenkins_scripts/prerelease", line 47, in <module>
    raise ex
RuntimeError: !!! multi_level_map is not a package name nor a repository name
```

As best I can tell, **multi_level_map** is *both* a metapackage name *and* a repository name.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59802/runtimeerror:-!!!-multi_level_map-is-not-a-package-name-nor-a-repository-name/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since there has been no answer, I suppose this must be a bug.

Ticket: [Jenkins issue #14](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/jenkins_tools/issues/14)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0